# Splitting weekday and weekend hours from start and end date not working for different weeks

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

Need to find total hours splitting the hours for the weekend which is Friday, Saturday and Sunday and other weekdays.
Using the following piece of code but it's not yielding the desired result.

```
$start_day = date('w', $start_time);
        $start_hour = date('G', $start_time);
        $end_day = date('w', $end_time);
        $end_hour = date('G', $end_time);
        $normal_hours = $surge_hours = 0;


        for (;($start_hour < 24 && $start_day <= $end_day); $start_hour++) {

            switch ($start_day) {
                case 0: $surge_hours++;
                    break;
                case 5: $surge_hours++;
                    break;
                case 6: $surge_hours++;
                    break;
                case 1: $normal_hours++;
                    break;
                case 2: $normal_hours++;
                    break;
                case 3: $normal_hours++;
                    break;
                case 4: $normal_hours++;
                    break;
            }
            echo __line__;
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r('surgehours'.$surge_hours);
            echo "<br/>";
            print_r('normalhours'.$normal_hours);
            echo "<pre/>";
            if ($start_hour == 23) {
                $start_hour = 0;
                $start_day++;
            }

            if ($start_day == $end_day) {
                if ($start_hour == $end_hour)
                    break;
            }
        }
```

**Failing Uses cases:**

If the start day is Friday, i.e.: 29 July and end day is 1 August ( `$start_day = 5 and $end_day = 1` )
It does not go into the loop.

Any ideas how to calculate the hours?

Comment: is your calculations limited by one week or it can be longer than one week/month/year ?

Comment: it can be anything @Wizard

Comment: You have too complex solution, and it has problems like, for example, your $start_day always increments inside the loop, and if it was 6, you'll have 7 for the next iteration.

Comment: @Wizard how to make it a simple solution and make it count the hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new code is below (cleaned it up and changed the comparison operator to < instead of <= which prevented that last extra hour from coming through):

```
    <?php
$start_time = strtotime('next friday 11am');
$end_time = $start_time + (60*60*24*3);

function allocate_hour($timestamp) {
    if(date('w',$timestamp) >= 5 OR date('w',$timestamp) == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else { return 1; }
}

$weekdayhours = 0;
$weekendhours = 0;
for($thistime=$start_time;$thistime<$end_time;$thistime+=3600){
    if(allocate_hour($thistime) === 1) { $weekdayhours++; } else { $weekendhours++; } // add 1 for each hour.
}

echo 'Weekday hours: '.$weekdayhours;
echo '<BR>weekend hours: '.$weekendhours;
```

Comment: why is this added in endtime (60*60*24*9) @jeff

Comment: It's arbitrary (just to setup the variable) - 60*60*24 = 1 day in seconds.

so, 60*60*24*9 = 9 days.

Comment: added  my output to the code written but total hours is calculate is 73.its 1 hour extra

Comment: Post what you addedand I'll have a look.

Comment: what I meant by that is - whatever you added* to the code, I'd like you to share so I can help you debug. When I run this I get the correct answer of 72 hours for the weekends days.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118299/discussion-between-saurabh-kamble-and-jeff).

Comment: That should do it. Feed this the start and end time and it will calculated the hours (splitting weekends) into this.

Answer (score 0):

Not so beautiful code, but it works:

> *Notice: dates limited by year*

```
<?php

// test values
$start_date = mktime(9,0,0,5,5,2016);   //  5-may-2016 (Thursday)
$end_date   = mktime(18,0,0,5,20,2016); // 20-may-2016 (Saturday)

// count days between dates
$days_between  = date('z',$end_date) - date('z', $start_date) + 1;
// guessing how many weekends days can be
$weekdays = floor($days_between/7)*3;

// get weekday nubmer 1-monday..7-sunday
$sday = date('N',$start_date);
$eday = date('N',$end_date);

// initialize counters
$surge = 0;
$normal = 0;

if ($days_between >=7) {
    // correct weekends days count
    // when we have more than 1 week difference
    switch ($sday) {
        case 7:
            $weekdays--;
        case 6:
            $weekdays--;
    }

    switch ($eday) {
        case 7:
            $weekdays++;
        case 6:
            $weekdays++;
        case 5:
            $weekdays++;
    }
} else {
    // correct weekends days count
    // when we have less than 1 week difference
    switch ($sday) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
            $weekdays++;
        case 6:
            $weekdays++;
        case 7:
            $weekdays++;
    }
    switch ($eday) {
        case 5:
            $weekdays--;
        case 6:
            $weekdays--;
    }
}

// remember start and end hours
$shour = date('G', $start_date);
$ehour = date('G', $end_date);

if ($sday == $eday) {
    // we're start and end at the same day
    if (in_array($sday, array(5,6,7))) {
        $surge += $ehour - $shour;
    } else {
        $normal += $ehour - $shour;
    }
} else {
    $first_day_hours = 24 - $shour;
    $last_day_hours  = $ehour;
    // decrease counter by two, because
    // the first and last days process separately
    $days_between -= 2;

    if (in_array($sday, array(5,6,7))) {
        $surge += $first_day_hours;
        $weekdays--;
    } else {
        $normal += $first_day_hours;
    }

    if (in_array($eday, array(5,6,7))) {
        $surge += $last_day_hours;
        $weekdays--;
    } else {
        $normal += $last_day_hours;
    }

    if ($days_between>0) {
        $surge += 24 * $weekdays;
        $normal += 24 * ($days_between - $weekdays);
    }
}


echo 'Normal: '.$normal.PHP_EOL;
echo ' Surge: '.$surge.PHP_EOL;
```

The code close to your source (using loop):

> *Notice: dates are not limited*

```
<?php

// test values
$start_date = mktime(9,0,0,5,5,2016);
$end_date   = mktime(18,0,0,5,20,2016);

// remember start and end hours
$shour = date('G', $start_date);
$ehour = date('G', $end_date);
$first_day_hours = 24 - $shour;
$last_day_hours  = $ehour;

$sdate = mktime(0,0,0,date('m',$start_date),date('d',$start_date)+1,date('Y',$start_date));
$edate = mktime(0,0,0,date('m',$end_date),date('d',$end_date)-1,date('Y',$end_date));

// initialize counters
$surge = 0;
$normal = 0;

if (in_array(date('N',$start_date), array(5,6,7))) {
    $surge += $first_day_hours;
} else {
    $normal += $first_day_hours;
}
if (in_array(date('N',$end_date), array(5,6,7))) {
    $surge += $last_day_hours;
} else {
    $normal += $last_day_hours;
}
while ($sdate<=$edate) {
    if (in_array(date('N',$sdate), array(5,6,7))) {
        $surge += 24;
    } else {
        $normal += 24;
    }
    $sdate = mktime(0,0,0,date('m',$sdate),date('d',$sdate)+1,date('Y',$sdate));
}
echo 'Normal: '.$normal.PHP_EOL;
echo ' Surge: '.$surge.PHP_EOL;
```